# I am getting an below mentioned error while configuring wordpress in my local system

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu

I want to work with wordpress and i have installed wordpress,mysql-server,mysql-client and php5 in my system.but i am getting an error like this while installing,
     Errors were encountered while processing:
 php5-curl
 php5-gd
 php5-mysql
 php5-pgsql
 phpmyadmin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code.

Could anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you did not install proper php lib,So please upgrade your php  by

```
apt-get upgrade php
```

and install

```
apt-get install php5-curl php5-gd php5-mysql php5-pgsql
```